# Android Studio... Why can't I debug?

Tags: android

[image]

When you debug it from the Android studio 2.3.3, is there any way to stop it from happening?
I tried to do a lot of things with Google search, but I couldn't solve it.
I am not good at English, so I ask you to explain it easily.

Comment: Don't wry about this alert its a just alert and don't press force close. After some time debugger will start automatically.

Comment: Go to run -> attach debugger to android process and click on the process

Comment: Upendra Shah  // I've waited two hours. Do you have to wait any longer?